# Database & Asset Syncing Between Environments

Tags: assets, database

I've recently setup a new cloud server for a client with a Craft Multi Environment setup. And I also would like to to be able to do the [Database & Asset Syncing Between Environments in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms) as in the excellent [nystudio107](https://nystudio107.com) article.

I have it setup at my work and it works really well as you just have to navigate to **/scripts** folder via the terminal, and then type `./pull_db.sh`

Like I said I have this setup at my office and it works really well. But on this new server I've setup I'm having an issue in that I get the following when I do the `./pull_db.sh`

`-bash: ./pull_db.sh: Permission denied`

I've checked the setting in the `.env.sh` that I've created and match what I have in the office setup. So need to work out why I'm getting the permission denied.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Does `pull_db.sh` have execute permissions set? i.e. `chmod +x pull_db.sh`

Comment: That was it. Awesome, thanks. Makes my life so much easier with the multi environment config and database and asset syncing. They should add it to Craft 3

Comment: make that the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -bash: ./pull_db.sh: Permission denied

The error indicates that the shell script doesn't have execute permissions.  Running this command should make it executable:

```
chmod +x pull_db.sh
```